# Pine script ternary operator gives an error

Tags: pine-script, trading

Why does `defval=second` work but `defval=third` doesn't?

```
//@version=4 
study(title="Test") 

//STEP 1 - Get main symbol 
getmain = syminfo.ticker

//STEP 2 - Add second symbol input 
second = "EURUSD"
third = getmain == "EURUSD"?"GBPUSD" : getmain == "GBPUSD"?"EURUSD" : "BTCUSD"

sym = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval=third)

//STEP 3 - plot
symbolClose = security(sym, timeframe.period, close)
plot(symbolClose, color=color.red)
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is automatically change the overlay/second chart to a specific pair based on the main ticker.

The error I am getting for the `defval=third` is:

```
line 16: Cannot call 'input' with arguments (title=literal string, type=const string, defval=string); available overloads: input(const bool, const string, const string, const bool, const string) => input bool; input(const integer, const string, const string, const integer, const integer, const bool, const integer, [const integer...], const string) => input integer; input(const float, const string, const string, const float, const float, const bool, const float, [const float...], const string) => input float; input(const string, const string, const string, const bool, [const string...], const string, const bool) => input string; input(series[float], const string, const string, const string) => series[float];
line 17: Undeclared identifier 'sym';
line 18: Undeclared identifier 'symbolClose'
```

Also, I have about 40 pairs to work through, is there a more efficient method to minimize all those if statements?

Comment: The problem is not coming from the operator syntax, but instead from the syminfo.ticker (when called inside the defval)

Comment: The message says that defval must be `const string` whereas you are using regular string, wich is series string. You must set exact value of defval, without conditional statements.